# restrict external SSH logins to specific users and allow intranet logins to all

Tags: ssh, intranet, accounting, server-settings

I would like to restrict external SSH logins to specific users and allow intranet logins (192.168.0.0/24) to all users. I would appreciate a complete example file for this scenario.

Comment: note that 192.168.0.0/8 is _not_ a valid private IP class, it should be a B or C class, /8 means a C class (192.x.x.x)

Comment: @AlberT: A /8 was equivalent to a class A, not a class C -- but for the sake of all that's holy, STOP USING CLASSFUL NOTATION.  It's not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not tested, you should be able to use something akin to.

```
Match Address *,!192.168.0.0/24
    DenyUsers *
    AllowUsers user1 user2 user3
```

This would go into your `sshd_config` file.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answers. I have also found the following sshd_config syntax at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=523477 :

```
AllowUsers john
AllowUsers *@192.168.0.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use host or public key authentication on the local LAN and then password authentication.

Than configure known hosts or known_keys for every PC in you intranet